# Silverstripe : Userdefined form not sending emails to the email address added from back end as email reciepient

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am using Silver stripe 3.0.

I have set up a contact us form using User defined form module. 
I have added three fields, "Email", "Name" and "Message".

> **When the user fills in the form and submits, the email is sent to the user but the email address which set as *"email recipients"* in the user defined form is not getting the email which is sent by the user.**

I have been trying to figure this out for around three days but all of no use. Can any one help me out as it is a sort of emergency for me.

For some reference I have printed the list of recipients in the `UserDefinedFrom.php` in this foreach:

```
foreach($recipients as $recipient){
    /// should get the email set at back end as well.. But not printing here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done... I figured out the issue which was related to overriding the $email->setTo with the email address coming from the form.